# Using if statements with multiple radio buttons to calculate a sum in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Basic 2010 and trying to calculate an Decimal amount using radio buttons.

The first radio buttons are declared constants representing the cost of a service.

The second set of radio buttons are for a discount amount.

The issue I am having is the value returning, no matter what discount button is selected is the value for the first if statement.

I feel like I should be using a case statement, unfortunately the book I am using is vague concerning case statements.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

```
If MakeoverRadioButton1.Checked + Discount10RadioButton5.Checked Then
    CostSelectedService1 = Makeover_Decimal - (Makeover_Decimal * 0.1)
    AmountSelectedServiceLabel3.Text = CostSelectedService1.ToString("C")
ElseIf MakeoverRadioButton1.Checked + Discount20RadioButton6.Checked Then
    CostSelectedService2 = Makeover_Decimal - (Makeover_Decimal * 0.2)
    AmountSelectedServiceLabel3.Text = CostSelectedService2.ToString("C")
ElseIf MakeoverRadioButton1.Checked + NoDiscountRadioButton7.Checked Then
    CostSelectedService = Makeover_Decimal
    AmountSelectedServiceLabel3.Text = CostSelectedService.ToString("C")
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant this:

```
If MakeoverRadioButton1.Checked AndAlso Discount10RadioButton5.Checked Then
```

As a side note, it seems like your cost and discounts are irrelevant to each other. In this case you should be able to cut it with two separate `If...ElseIf` or `Select Case`. Otherwise you are looking for **n*m** `If` statements, which is hard to maintain.

If you want a more specific advice, and a code sample, please elaborate in your question on which radio buttons you currently have and how it's supposed to work (include a screenshot).

Comment: That defiantly worked. As you can tell I am pretty new to this, is there an easier way to write this code? it just seems like a lot code for a simple procedure.

Comment: @StickintheMud: Most likely there is, please update your question with a screenshot, and I'll write something up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified:

```
' the default
CostSelectedService = Makeover_Decimal
AmountSelectedServiceLabel3.Text = CostSelectedService.ToString("C")

If MakeoverRadioButton1.Checked AndAlso Discount10RadioButton5.Checked Then
   CostSelectedService1 -= (Makeover_Decimal * 0.1)

ElseIf MakeoverRadioButton1.Checked AndAlso Discount20RadioButton6.Checked Then
   CostSelectedService2 -= (Makeover_Decimal * 0.2)

End If
```